# Matlab symbolic - check if a function can be expressed in terms of another one

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

It is a bit hard to explain this in the title, so let's say that I have the standard sigmoid function in a symbolic expression and its derivative

```
f = 1/(1+exp(-x))
f2 = exp(-x)/(1+exp(-x))^2
```

again easily obtainable as symbolic expression. What I want is somehow to check that in fact `f2=f1(1-f1)`, e.g., (which is always the case for any injective function f), but do this automatically.

Comment: Do you want to check if such a relation exists, or to actually find it? For the former, an (imperfect) method is to sample (f2(x)-f2(y))/(f1(x)-f1(y)) over various x,y; if the ratio stays bounded, then f2 is a (Lipschitz) function of f1. This does not detect non-Lipschitz dependencies such as f2=sqrt(f1).

Comment: I need to actually find it, and I hope there is a symbolic way for doing this. The main idea is to analyse the expression simplified and find out given the fact that I need to evaluate f, should I use f2(x) or f2(f) as a faster numerical calculation, potentially and in terms of numerical stability

Comment: Basically, you want to eliminate x from the two equations. I don't have Matlab symbolic toolbox, but I have Maple which is somewhat similar. In Maple, it's `eliminate([f = 1/(1+exp(-x)), f2 = exp(-x)/(1+exp(-x))^2], x)` and the output is `f2 + f^2 - f = 0` which is the sort of result you wanted.

Comment: For functions that matlab symbolic toolbox can handle in a good way (the example is one of these), you may be able to use symbolic arithmetics: `f3=f2+f^2-f; simpify(f3)`. I am not sure how the proposal from [@FamousBlueRaincoat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28868361/matlab-symbolic-check-if-a-function-can-be-expressed-in-terms-of-another-one#comment46004196_28868361) can be implemented in matlab, but if that works it seems as a good solution as well.

Comment: I checked and in the symbolic toolbox unfortantely does not have this capability. And you are right that it might simplify it, but what essentially I would like to do is to have only an analytical expression for f, than use the symbolic toolbox to calculate Jf (jacobian) and have a way of analysing whether the Jacobian is easier to compute from the values of x or from the values of f(x), since I would be computing both f(x) and Jf(x).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least in this case you should be able to do this just using [`subs`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html), which works for expressions as well as variables:

```
syms x f1;
f = 1/(1+exp(-x))
f2 = exp(-x)/(1+exp(-x))^2
f2 = subs(f2,f,f1)
```

which in R2014b and R2015a returns `f1^2*exp(-x)`. For more complex expression this may not be completely robust or may need to be applied more than once or in conjunction with [`simplify`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/simplify.html).

If you just need to compare expressions, you can use [`sym/isequaln`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/isequaln.html) or [`isAlways`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/isalways.html):

```
syms x;
f = 1/(1+exp(-x));
f2 = exp(-x)/(1+exp(-x))^2;
isequaln(f*(1-f),f2)
isAlways(f*(1-f)==f2)
```

However, both of these return Boolean `false` (0). for some reason. This may be a bug or maybe it's because the to two forms have different singularities when evaluated at `-Inf`. The following

```
syms x;
f = 1/(1+exp(-x));
f2 = exp(-x)/(1+exp(-x))^2;
subs(f2,x,-Inf)
subs(f*(1-f),x,-Inf)
```

yields `NaN` and `0`, respectively. Taking the [`limit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/limit.html) at `-Inf` does yield the correct values, however. The documentation does not indicate how `sym/isequaln` and/or `isAlways` handle this situation. This might be a good case to [file a service request](http://www.mathworks.com/company/aboutus/contact_us/?s_tid=gn_cntus) with The MathWorks.

Comment: Just to point out that in fact 'exp(x)/(exp(x)+1)^2 = exp(-x)/(1+exp(-x))^2' (Just multiply numerator and denominator on right with e^(x^2)) Also the given expressions give me true on my Matlab. Otherwise I guess I'll accept this as answer as it gets me as close as possible (actually it seems to do what I want, but have to test it a bit). Thanks!

Comment: @Belov: Thank you. Yes, I was to quick with my mental math and switched around the different `f` variables. I've updated my answer with some corrections and clarifications. Hopefully there's something in this answer that you can use to solve your problem. If you're using an older `version` of Matlab, it's possible that you could see different results as the the Symbolic Math toolbox has changed a lot in recent years.

Comment: So I'm not sure what does isequaln does for symbolic so Boolean False(0) could be ok(maybe it compares the symbolic expression as strings?). As for my machine isAlways(f*(1-f)==f2) gives True, as well as simplify(f*(1-f)-f2) gives 0. I'm using Matlab 2014a, but I'm on a Linux kernel, so there might be and some diff between the windows version idk.

Comment: @Belov: `isequaln` is definitely doing more than just comparing strings. I'm on OS X. I'd guess that the difference is due to your use of R2014a instead of R2014b+. However, the `simplify(f*(1-f)-f2)` trick does work as expected for me.